# Install Ubuntu on an external hard drive

Tags: 14.04, performance

If I install Ubuntu on an external hard drive USB 3.0 is it gonna be slow to work on and do some gaming (Metro, borderlands etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. As being compatible with USB 3.0 as well as if it is SSD supported, performance of the hard drive will be much greater than internal hard drive.

Comment: I'd prefer an Internal HD's over an external, have had trouble with USB connectivity, reliability, speed, and external HD enclosure quality can be all over the place. *If* everything on the usb HD works right then it could be the same speed as if it were plugged in internally, no faster.